# How to use Genetic Algorithm (GA) for feature selection in an SMS Spam/Ham dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, spam-prevention

I'm working on a school ML project to detect Spam SMS, so i have my dataset, my problem now is to be able to select features from the dataset using Genetic Algorithm i don't really know how to achieve that, and is a must according to the project description, please i need help Thanks.

```
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def textPreProcess(text):
    punctuationsToNone = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    text = text.translate(punctuationsToNone)
    text = [word for word in text.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words("english")]
    return " ".join(text)
```

## feature extraction with genetic algorithm

from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")

def stemming(text):
    words = map(lambda t: SnowballStemmer("english").stem(t), text.split())
    return " ".join(words)

## We make a copy of the message into a new DataFrame

texts = sms['message'].copy()

```
# And apply the pre-processing methods to the new DataFrame
texts = texts.apply(textPreProcess)
texts = texts.apply(stemming)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer("english")
features = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)
```

this is my progress on the feature selection, but i think am doing the wrong thing.

Comment: What have you tried? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to make it easier for us to help.

Comment: i have edited the question like hours ago, sorry that was a mistake.

Comment: i have done the pre-processing and working on the feature selection which i used 'TfidVectorizer',  but i was asked specifically to use a Genetic Algorithm to select the feature